# How to add name attribute if checkbox is checked and if it is unchecked than remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a checkbox inside a for loop, so I want only the checkbox that is checked to have a name attribute.
I tried but when I clicked on the second checkbox, the name of the first attribute is not removed.
Here is my code :

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {

var $box = $(this);
if ($box.is(":checked")) {

  var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";

  $(group).prop("checked", false);
  $box.prop("checked", true);
} else {
  $box.prop("checked", false);
}
});

$('select ,input[type=checkbox] ').on('change', function() {
  var selector = $(this).closest("tr")//get closest tr

  //get select valus
    var id = selector.attr('data-id');
    // var package_name = selector.find('.visa_type').val();
    var processing_type = selector.find(".processing_type option:selected").text();
    // alert(processing_type)
    var processing_price = selector.find(".processing_type option:selected").val();
    // alert(processing_price)
    var add = selector.find(".package_price").text(processing_price)
    var total = add.val()
    var date = selector.find('.travel_date').val();

  if(selector.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked") == true){
    //id
    selector.find('.id').attr('name','id')

    //visa_type
    selector.find('.visa_type').attr('name','visa_type');

    //processing_type
    selector.find(".processing_type").attr('name','processing_type');

    //traveldate
    selector.find('.travel_date').attr('name','travel_date');

    //total
    selector.find(".package_price").attr('name','total','value',total)


  }else if(selector.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked") == false){
    //id
    selector.find('.id').attr('name','')

    //visa_type
    selector.find('.visa_type').attr('name','');

    //processing_type
    selector.find(".processing_type").attr('name','');

    //traveldate
    selector.find('.travel_date').attr('name','');

    //total
    selector.find(".package_price").attr('name','')

  }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table  table-bordered table-responsive" id="flip-scroll">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Visa Option</th>
                            <th scope="col">Processing Type</th>
                            <th height="60" scope="col">Travel Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        
                                                <tr class="valid-container">
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1">
                                                    <td style="cursor:pointer;" width="200"><input type="checkbox" name="c1" class="checkbox">&nbsp; <output class="visa_type" style="font-size:14.5px !important;" value="90 days single visa">90 days single visa</output></td>

                                      <td height="52" width="158">
                                                        <select class="custom-select processing_type" required="">
                                                            <option value="15000" selected="">Normal</option>
                                                            <option value="20000">Express</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>


                                      <td width="190" height="60">

                                                        <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
                                                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control travel_date" value="dd.mm.yyyy" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
                                                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-calendar"></i></div>
                                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </td>

                                      <td width="166">AED&nbsp;&nbsp; <output class="package_price">15000</output>.00</td>

                                    </tr>
                        
                                                <tr class="valid-container">
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2">
                                                    <td style="cursor:pointer;" width="200"><input type="checkbox" name="c1" class="checkbox">&nbsp; <output class="visa_type" style="font-size:14.5px !important;" value="30 days">30 days</output></td>

                                      <td height="52" width="158">
                                                        <select class="custom-select processing_type" required="">
                                                            <option value="11" selected="">Normal</option>
                                                            <option value="22">Express</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>


                                      <td width="190" height="60">

                                                        <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
                                                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control travel_date" value="dd.mm.yyyy" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
                                                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-calendar"></i></div>
                                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </td>

                                      <td width="166">AED&nbsp;&nbsp; <output class="package_price">11</output>.00</td>

                                    </tr>
                        
                                                <tr class="valid-container">
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="3">
                                                    <td style="cursor:pointer;" width="200"><input type="checkbox" name="c1" class="checkbox">&nbsp; <output class="visa_type" style="font-size:14.5px !important;" value="90 days">90 days</output></td>

                                      <td height="52" width="158">
                                                        <select class="custom-select processing_type" required="">
                                                            <option value="22" selected="">Normal</option>
                                                            <option value="33">Express</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>


                                      <td width="190" height="60">

                                                        <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
                                                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control travel_date" value="dd.mm.yyyy" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
                                                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-calendar"></i></div>
                                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </td>

                                      <td width="166">AED&nbsp;&nbsp; <output class="package_price">22</output>.00</td>

                                    </tr>
                        

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: @quantumPuter Can you help me

Comment: Make the code runnable here or in a jsfiddle.  Use the generated HTML.

Comment: Hi , you mean only one checkbox should be checked at a time ?

Comment: yes,And when clicked on the checkbox the name should be Attribute Add

Comment: why not use radio button instead of checkbox ?

Comment: I tried but the name of the checkbox which I checked earlier is not leaving the attribute

Comment: My client said to add checkbox

Comment: The user will select the checkbox to submit the complete data form for that payment.

Comment: @Swati & quantumPuter This is my first payment application and the client is behind me please help me or tell me some other way to take data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to select only one checkbox at a time you can remove `checked` from other checkboxes whenever any checkbox is checked using `$('tbody > tr .checkbox').not(this).prop('checked',false);` then you just need to loop through your `trs` to add or remove `name` attributes.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox] ').on('change', function() {
  $('tbody > tr .checkbox').not(this).prop('checked',false);//remove checked from other checkbox
  //loop thrugh trs
  $("tbody > tr").each(function() {
//add or remove name attribute
   var selector = $(this)
    if (selector.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked") == true) {
      selector.find('.visa_type').attr('name', 'visa_type');
      selector.find(".processing_type").attr('name', 'processing_type');
      selector.find('.travel_date').attr('name', 'travel_date');

    } else if (selector.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked") == false) {
      selector.find('.visa_type').attr('name', '');
      selector.find(".processing_type").attr('name', '');
      selector.find('.travel_date').attr('name', '');

    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table  table-bordered table-responsive" id="flip-scroll">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Visa Option</th>
      <th scope="col">Processing Type</th>
      <th height="60" scope="col">Travel Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


    <tr class="valid-container">
      <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1">
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" width="200"><input type="checkbox" name="c1" class="checkbox">&nbsp; <output class="visa_type" style="font-size:14.5px !important;" value="90 days single visa">90 days single visa</output></td>

      <td height="52" width="158">
        <select class="custom-select processing_type" required="">
          <option value="15000" selected="">Normal</option>
          <option value="20000">Express</option>
        </select>
      </td>


      <td width="190" height="60">

        <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control travel_date" value="dd.mm.yyyy" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-calendar"></i></div>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </td>

      <td width="166">AED&nbsp;&nbsp; <output class="package_price">15000</output>.00</td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="valid-container">
      <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2">
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" width="200"><input type="checkbox" name="c1" class="checkbox">&nbsp; <output class="visa_type" style="font-size:14.5px !important;" value="30 days">30 days</output></td>

      <td height="52" width="158">
        <select class="custom-select processing_type" required="">
          <option value="11" selected="">Normal</option>
          <option value="22">Express</option>
        </select>
      </td>


      <td width="190" height="60">

        <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control travel_date" value="dd.mm.yyyy" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-calendar"></i></div>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </td>

      <td width="166">AED&nbsp;&nbsp; <output class="package_price">11</output>.00</td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="valid-container">
      <input type="hidden" class="id" value="3">
      <td style="cursor:pointer;" width="200"><input type="checkbox" name="c1" class="checkbox">&nbsp; <output class="visa_type" style="font-size:14.5px !important;" value="90 days">90 days</output></td>

      <td height="52" width="158">
        <select class="custom-select processing_type" required="">
          <option value="22" selected="">Normal</option>
          <option value="33">Express</option>
        </select>
      </td>


      <td width="190" height="60">

        <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control travel_date" value="dd.mm.yyyy" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="ti-calendar"></i></div>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </td>

      <td width="166">AED&nbsp;&nbsp; <output class="package_price">22</output>.00</td>

    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```